# How to find the slant asymptote for $y=\frac{x^2\arctan\left(x\right)}{3x+3}$

Tags: calculus

I got stuck at the end and wonder if you can give some guide on how to proceed to find the slant asymptote?
$$y=\frac{x^2\arctan\left(x\right)}{3x+3}$$

---

$$y= kx+m\\
\frac{f(x)}{x} \rightarrow k\\
f(x) - kx \rightarrow m $$

---

Solution:

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\frac{x^2\arctan\left(x\right)}{3x+3}}{x}\:\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{x^2\arctan\left(x\right)}{x(3x+3)}\:\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{x^2\arctan\left(x\right)}{(3x^{2\:\:}+3x)}\:\right)\\
=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2} \cdot\frac{\arctan\left(x\right)}{(3+\frac{3}{x})}\:\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}\Longrightarrow k=\frac{\pi}{6}\\
f(x)-kx \implies \frac{x^2\arctan\left(x\right)}{3x+3} - \frac{\pi}{6} \cdot {x}\\
\frac{6\cdot x^2\arctan -3\pi{x^2} - 3\pi {x}}{18(x+1)}$$
Searching for $m$.

Comment: Can you use Taylor expansion ?

Answer (score 3):

$\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$ for $x\to \infty$, hence
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left[\frac{x^2\arctan(x)}{3x+3}-\frac{\pi}{6}x\right]=\lim_{x\to +\infty}-\frac{(2+\pi ) x}{6 (1+x)}=-\frac{\pi+2}{6} $$
and the equation of the slant asymptote is $y=\frac{\pi}{6}x-\frac{\pi+2}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Put $y=\frac 1x$ and use the fact that

for $y>0$, we have

$$\arctan(\frac 1y)=\frac {\pi}{2}-\arctan(y)$$

use L'Hopital rule to compute the limit when $y\to 0^+$.